# ASP.NET Core Web API - Static class 'UserUniqueEmailValidator' cannot derive from type 'ValidationAttribute'. Static classes must derive from object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Entity Framework project, I have this custom Email Validator using Data Annotation.

```
public static class UserUniqueEmailValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public static UserUniqueEmailValidator(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public static bool IsUniqueUserEmailValidator(string email)
    {
        if (_dbContext.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()) == null) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Error    CS0713  Static class 'UserUniqueEmailValidator' cannot derive from type 'ValidationAttribute'. Static classes must derive from object

> Error CS0708  'UserUniqueEmailValidator._dbContext': cannot declare instance members in a static class

> Error CS0515  'UserUniqueEmailValidator.UserUniqueEmailValidator(ApplicationDbContext)': access modifiers are not allowed on static constructors

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Remove all `static` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Try using it like this:

```
public class UserUniqueEmailValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext _dbContext { get; set; }
    public UserUniqueEmailValidator(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public static bool IsUniqueUserEmailValidator(string email)
    {
        if (_dbContext.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.ToLower() == email.ToLower()) == null) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

static classes cannot have constructors or derive from no static objects.

Comment: I did exactly as you advised but got this error:     An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'UserUniqueEmailValidator._dbContext'

Comment: You have the ApplicationDbContext in the constructor. Are you passing in the context?

Comment: I forgot to make the context static as well. I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks so much. But one last thing. How do I apply it to this in data annotation:   public string Email { get; set; }